# TOC with different page alignment for same style in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, table-of-contents, alignment

I have added a TOC to my document automatically based on the styles across the document. Strangely some page number alignment is different for the same style (screenshot below). I have tried changing the stoptabs but that messed up all the TOC. Anyone got a good idea on how to solve this? Many thanks in advance!

Below a link to a sample of the word document:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XEbtcId0kNegqNYxqWrIHrGXNvan4ewB/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102809693372772800726&rtpof=true&sd=true

Problem in document for TOC1:

[image: screenshot of problem in document for TOC1]

Problem in document TOC3:

[image: screenshot of problem in document TOC3]

Comment: Try to add a tab after the original title entry. Hopefully it'll solve your issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### That has to do with the tab setting in the TOC style and the settings in your MultiLevel Numbering List.

There is likely a left tab set where the errant page number is showing up. If you remove the tab stop it will give you the dot leader and right alignment.

Note where the text ends on the entries that show the problem.

Here is a [temporary link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqq8xd2y9fh3oi7/deleteme%20sample.docx?dl=0) to your sample document repaired.

Steps I took:

1. I used the Define MultiLevel List dialog for your numbering in the document to change the character following your numbering from a tab to a space.
2. I changed the tab settings for your TOC styles to have a right tab outside the right indent. Yours had it at 5.69" and I set it for 6 inches. This was done using the Tabs dialog, not the ruler.
3. I changed the paragraph settings for TOC 3 to have a hanging indent. This was done using the Paragraph Format dialog.

I would suggest that you make a copy of your document and try importing the following styles from my repaired document into your copy and see if that helps:

- Heading 1-4
- TOC 1-4

Use the [Organizer](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Organizer) to import the styles. *(The link is to my page on Styles.)*

Comment: Hi Charles, thank you so much for making yourself available to have a look at the document. I couldn't find any difference in the tab stops between the "correct" and "odd" entries. Again I have used styles to define how I want the text to look like in the document and for that reason I can't find a reason for having text with expectedly the same style displaying different formats in TOC. I have added a  link to a sample of the word document (via google drive) in case you can provide some insights. Many thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer and included a temporary link to a repaired version  of your document. https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqq8xd2y9fh3oi7/deleteme%20sample.docx?dl=0

Comment: Many thanks Charles! Problem solved :)

Comment: You are welcome. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers